# Mikrotik - lots of tcp retransmission packets

Tags: routing, router, nat, mikrotik

I have a ubuntu server with ip 192.168.10.144, in this server I have a docker network using ip range 10.0.0.0/24. I need connect my computer to some services running in docker, so I've added a route in Mikrotik:

```
#      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
0 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          192.168.0.1               1
1 A S  10.0.0.0/24                        192.168.10.144            1
2 ADC  192.168.0.0/24     192.168.0.3     ether1-internet           0
3 ADC  192.168.10.0/24    192.168.10.1    ether2-proliant           0
```

However the connection between my computer and docker services are extremely slow. I used wireshark to check what was happening and found some of tcp-restransmission messages:

[image: wireshark]

I've though a nat rule could solve the problem, however when using the following rules, no communication was made between my computer and docker:

```
0    ;;; default configuration
  chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=ether1-internet log=no 
  log-prefix="" 

1    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.10.144 to-ports=80 
  protocol=tcp dst-port=8000 log=no log-prefix="" 

2 X  chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.10.144 protocol=tcp 
  dst-address=10.0.0.0/24 log=no log-prefix="" 

3 X  chain=srcnat action=src-nat to-addresses=10.0.0.0/24 protocol=tcp 
  src-address=192.168.10.144 log=no log-prefix=""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply deleted the nat rules and added a masquerade rule:

```
[admin@MikroTik] /ip firewall nat> print 
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 0    ;;; default configuration chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=ether1-internet log=no log-prefix="" 
 1    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.10.144 to-ports=80 protocol=tcp dst-port=8000 log=no log-prefix="" 
 2    chain=srcnat action=masquerade dst-address=10.0.0.0/24 log=no log-prefix=""
```

Now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC has IP address 192.168.10.53? You send traffic to host 10.0.0.77 via your default gateway - 192.168.10.1. Your router send you back ICMP redirect packets. You can read more about that here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13714-43.html

You possibly get something similar to problem described here: https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=139465

Possible solution:
Set static route on your PC: `10.0.0.0/24 via 192.168.10.144`